# Create object of abstract class. How possible

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class

Why it is possible? :

```
BitmapSource i = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(...);
```

I'm writing some app n i find this line and im cunfused, because MSDN says that BitmapSource is abstract class.

Comment: You create a class that derives from BitmapSource.

Comment: Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. You need to create an instance of a derived class. This example works because the implementation of the static factory method will be creating a derived class. Inspect the actual runtime type of the object returned by the method in the debugger and you will see.

Answer (score 8):

`BitmapSource` is an abstract class and thus can't be created *directly*, but `Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap` returns some concrete class that *inherits* from `BitmapSource` and thus can be "cast" to a `BitmapSource`.

It's analagous to having an abstract `Animal` class, but having a concrete `Giraffe` class that inherits from it:

```
Animal a = new Animal();  // illegal
Animal a = Zoo.CreateAnimalFromName("Giraffe"); // valid - returns a Giraffe instance
```

Comment: Im always amazed at how many zoo monitoring software developers there are on this site.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap` returns some concrete class which inherits from `BitmapSource`. So this call does not create an instance of the abstract class `BitmapSource`. You were just confused about this.

To simplify the situation, this is similar to
`Animal an1 = DogFactory.createDog();`
or to
`Animal an2 = CatFactory.createCat();`
if we assume `Animal` is an abstract class, while `Cat`
and `Dog` are concrete classes which inherit from `Animal`.

Answer (score 1):

`BitmapSource` is an abstract class but `Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap` creates an object with type of concrete subclass `InteropBitmap`, you can see it in [.NET reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/src/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Interop/Imaging.cs#086634f6048b5cd6):

```
unsafe public static BitmapSource CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
    IntPtr bitmap,
    IntPtr palette,
    Int32Rect sourceRect,
    BitmapSizeOptions sizeOptions)
{
    SecurityHelper.DemandUnmanagedCode();

    // CR: [....] (1681459)
    return CriticalCreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap, palette, sourceRect, sizeOptions, WICBitmapAlphaChannelOption.WICBitmapUseAlpha);
}

unsafe internal static BitmapSource CriticalCreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
    IntPtr bitmap,
    IntPtr palette,
    Int32Rect sourceRect,
    BitmapSizeOptions sizeOptions,
    WICBitmapAlphaChannelOption alphaOptions)
{
    if (bitmap == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");
    } 
    return new InteropBitmap(bitmap, palette, sourceRect, sizeOptions, alphaOptions); // use the critical version
}
```

And you can assign `InteropBitmap` to `BitmapSource` type variable because it is its base class (directly or not), exactly as in:

```
interface ISomeInterface { };
abstract class SomeBaseClass : ISomeInterfac { };
class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass { };
```

and then you can:

```
ISomeInterface var1 = new SomeClass();
```

or:

```
SomeBaseClass var2 = new SomeClass();
```

and eventually you can create some factory method that hides creating an object:

```
class SomeFactoryClass
{
   public SomeBaseClass CreateObject() { return new SomeClass(); }
}

SomeBaseClass var3 = SomeFactoryClass.CreateObject();
```

Exactly as in the above exept from the .NET reference source code.